# Can't select Excel sheet from PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell-2.0

I am just learning PowerShell and am unfortunately stuck with using v2 instead of the latest version. What I am trying to do is open Excel 2010 and select a specific worksheet. The problem is that I cannot select the worksheet I am interested in. Here is my code:

```
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible=$True
$workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($excelfile)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq 'AnalysisMain'}
Write-Output "worksheet: $worksheet"
```

I have verified that the sheet name is spelled correctly and the code looks good to me however the result is that no worksheet is ever returned - the result is null.

Where have I gone off the rails?

Comment: `$worksheet = $workbook.workwheets.item("AnalysisMain")`

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried that statement as well but that results in the exception: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression and points specifically to that line of code.

Comment: I got that from here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/08/copy-data-from-one-excel-spreadsheet-to-another-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Double-check the name of the worksheet. Does `$wb.Worksheets | % { '-{0}-' -f $_.Name }` perhaps show leading or trailing whitespace?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Running that command just returns '--'. Shouldn't the name appear between the hyphens?

Comment: @user5013 Yes. But the line should've been `$workbook.Worksheets | % { '-{0}-' -f $_.Name }`. Copy/paste error from my test system. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

In my testing this:

```
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible=$True
$workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open('C:\\_Stuff\\test.xlsx')
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item('Sheet1')
Write-Output $worksheet.name
```

Produced the expected output "Sheet1"

This also worked:

```
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible=$True
$workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open('C:\\_Stuff\\test.xlsx')
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq 'Sheet1'}
Write-Output $worksheet.name
```

Are you sure your `$workbook` object is being set ?

Comment: My tests yielded the same results, so I'm suspecting an issue with the sheet name (misplaced whitespace perhaps). If there were a problem with opening the workbook he should be getting an error at some point. Escaping backslashes in the path is not required, BTW.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - thanks: wasn't sure about the backslashes - my first time trying Powershell...

Answer (score 0):

Copying excel data based on the range on the sheet and writing into the email body

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open('D:\Projects\working\data.xlsm')
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item('Graph')
$sheet.activate()
$rangeSource=$sheet.range("A50","M73")
$rangeSource.Copy() | out-null
$Results = Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html | select -skip 7 | Out-String
```

**Following data will be skipped**

Version:1.0 StartHTML:0000000174 EndHTML:0000035258 StartFragment:0000001674 EndFragment:0000035206 SourceURL:file:///D:\Projects\working\data.xlsx